# How do I store &lt; in a string without it being treated as HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been working on a javascript program that colors code to simulate an IDE in a browser.  It looks at any code in the class .code, looks for keywords, and right now for testing it just colors them red or blue, and I'm only passing a handful of keywords.  I'll add more colors and keywords once it's working.

It works fine right now, tomorrow I'll implement a check to try to keep it from coloring keywords that are inside words (like coloring "for" in "forward") except for one problem.

At the bottom of my test code, I have `&lt;` and `&gt;` on two lines.  For some reason, my code turns those back into the < and > signs which then screw with my formatting because my browser thinks they're meant to be HTML.

```
function paintKeyword() {
    var spanOpenRed = `<span class="key_red">`;
    var spanOpenBlue = `<span class="key_blue">`;
    var spanClose = `</span>`;
    var index = 1;  //index goes through the keywords which begin at position 1 not 0
    var initCodeString = arguments[0];
    var newCodeString = "";
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    for(index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
        do {
            end = initCodeString.indexOf(arguments[index],start);
            newCodeString += initCodeString.slice(start,end);
            console.log(newCodeString);
            newCodeString += spanOpenRed + arguments[index] + spanClose;
            start = end + arguments[index].length;
        }
        while(end != -1);
        initCodeString = newCodeString;
        newCodeString = "";
        start = 0;
    }
    for(index = 4; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        do {
            end = initCodeString.indexOf(arguments[index],start);
            newCodeString += initCodeString.slice(start,end);
            console.log(newCodeString);
            newCodeString += spanOpenBlue + arguments[index] + spanClose;
            start = end + arguments[index].length;
        }
        while(end != -1);
        initCodeString = newCodeString;
        newCodeString = "";
        start = 0;
    }
    $(".code").html(initCodeString);
}

(function colorCode() {
    var codeText = $(".code").text();
    paintKeyword(codeText, "function","var","return","for","of","in","new");
})();
```

Note that I used the IIFE for the sake of practicing writing IIFEs.  But quite simply, all it does is parse through whatever text is in the `.code` class and replace keywords with `<span class="key_{color}>{keyword}</span>`.  This is not a finished code and right now, aside from the bug I'm asking about it does what I intend to do so far.  What I don't understand is why it's turning the `&lt;` and `&gt;` back into angular brackets and what I can do to keep it from doing that.

If it helps, the code in the `.code` class on the page this is being run on is the same as in my jsfidde: https://jsfiddle.net/jkuhl/z46vmrLe/

It's the four lines at the very bottom with the `<p>` tags that are causing the problem.  On my website, the browser is treating them as real p tags, despite me using the `&lt;` symbols and it's my JavaScript doing this because it wasn't doing this before I wrote the program.

Code Pen:  https://codepen.io/jkuhl/pen/vZmjVb

Comment: Can you create a complete minimally verifiable example that demonstrates the behavior? Include inputs, expected output and actual output.

Comment: have you looked at innerText  instead of innerHTML?

Comment: @mkaatman if you put \[mcve] in your comment it comes out like [mcve].  Alternatively, if you put a backslash before the first open bracket, it comes out like \[mcve]

Comment: @xaxxon sweet. That will come in handy. Thank you. Is there a list of supported commands I don't know about?

Comment: @mkaatman that is the only one I know of.

Comment: If I use jQuery's .text() or vanilla's .innerText, that just causes the code to completely ignore all the span tags that give the words color.

Comment: @JonathanKuhl You should be setting the text of the span...

Comment: @JonathanKuhl Have you considered using one of the several web-based code editor components that already exist to build your project with?